# Not able to integrate my youtube channel to business API . Error while integrating is "Whoops! You're using an account that can't go here."

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Channel Url - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEhPngLsBZQIeG5dRDoeJIg
Error while connection youtube account to business app.
The following image shows that the youtube acoount exist under the brand (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TI0O.png)
When we click on the channel mentioned in the image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1svs.png)
Following error occurs while integration(https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6l4T.png)

Tried integrating the channel to my business App.
Excepting to channel should be integrated on business app.

Comment: if this is a programing related question please edit your question and include your code